# change the query to return categorized output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query like this:

```
select * from my_table;
```

and the result is like below:

```
name       x1    x2    x3
----       ---- ---   ---
data       -2    3      -1
```

I want to change the query to divide positive and negative output into separated row and the result change to :

```
name       x1    x2    x3
----       ---- ---   ---
data       -2    3      -1
data       -2    null   -1
data       null  3      null
```

Comment: Use CASE for each separate column and UNION ALL for 2 queries - one selects negative values only, and another selects only non-negative (positive or zero) values.

Comment: thank you, but my real query is too long and I do not want to use union. @Akina

Comment: *but my real query is too long and I do not want to use union* Put your query to CTE then reuse it in UNION ALL.

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are two separate RDBMS; which are you using?

Comment: I use Oracle database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your query is complicated, you can put it into a sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause and then use `UNION ALL` and `CASE` expressions:

```sql
WITH your_query (name, x1, x2, x3) AS (
  select * from my_table
)
SELECT *
FROM   your_query
UNION ALL
SELECT name,
       CASE WHEN x1 < 0 THEN x1 END,
       CASE WHEN x2 < 0 THEN x2 END,
       CASE WHEN x3 < 0 THEN x3 END
FROM   your_query
UNION ALL
SELECT name,
       CASE WHEN x1 >= 0 THEN x1 END,
       CASE WHEN x2 >= 0 THEN x2 END,
       CASE WHEN x3 >= 0 THEN x3 END
FROM   your_query;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT *
    FROM   my_Table
    SELECT name,
           CASE WHEN x1 < 0 THEN x1 else Null END,
           CASE WHEN x2 < 0 THEN x2 else Null END,
           CASE WHEN x3 < 0 THEN x3 else Null END
    FROM   my_Table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name,
           CASE WHEN x1 >= 0 THEN x1 else Null END,
           CASE WHEN x2 >= 0 THEN x2 else Null END,
           CASE WHEN x3 >= 0 THEN x3 else Null END
    FROM   my_Table;
```